# Features menu import/export

Tags: routes, navigation, features, importing-exporting

I am having an issue with exporting my main menu with the features module. I go to features > module_name > recreate > menu_links and then check all the links that I want.
Once I import the feature on a fresh instance, not all of the menu links show up. If I go to features > module_name > overridden > menu_links all of the links show up there but when I click revert changes, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a couple months late, but I encountered the same issue and wanted to answer this in case someone runs into the same problem.

Basically, Features will not show menu links unless the link path is identical.  So, the paths on the site you're importing to have to be identical to the ones from you're exporting from.  If they are different, nothing shows.

If you open up the links.inc file you'll see:

```
 $menu_links['menu-primary:node/1'] = array(
   'menu_name' => 'menu-primary',
   'link_path' => 'node/1',
```

You can manually modify the link path to make things show up, but obviously this isn't ideal.  Hopefully this gets addressed down the road...really a killer in my opinion.